# Lower limit of $\sqrt[n]{1^n+2^n+...+n^n}$ with sandwich rule

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I was asked to find (by the sandwich rule) the limit of: $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\sqrt[n]{1^n+2^n+...+n^n}}$$

The upper limit is quite immidiate: $C_n = \sqrt[n]{n^n+n^n+...+n^n}$.

As for the lower part I'm facing quite an understanding conflict:

I'm looking for $A_n$ for which: $$\forall n\in \mathbb{N}: a_n \leq \sqrt[n]{1^n+2^n+...+n^n}$$
So I wanted to pick $\sqrt[n]{1^n+1^n+...+1^n}$  but I have a dillema:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\sqrt[n]{1^n+1^n+...+1^n}} = 1$$
OR
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\sqrt[n]{1^n+1^n+...+1^n}} = \infty$$

1. Since $1$ to any power is $1$ we obviously get: $1^n=1$. Therefor we have $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\sqrt[n]{1^n+1^n+...+1^n}} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\sqrt[n]{n}} = 1$$
2. Since $n \rightarrow \infty$ we have infinite amounts of $1$'s. Therefore we virtually have $\infty$ under the $\sqrt[n]{}$ sign.

Ultimately I can't seem to determine what's the limit: $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\sqrt[n]{1^n+1^n+...+1^n}}$.

Is there a ground rule that helps me decide? I'm more prone to decide to go with what I know: $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\sqrt[n]{n}} = 1$$
But since I have an inifinite number under the root, Im a bit skeptical. Plus, I already know the answer is $\infty$, but I insist on solving this conflict of mind.

Comment: No, you don't an infinite number under the root: for any $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$ you have a pretty finite number under the root, namely the number $\;\sqrt[n]{1^n+\ldots +1^n}=\sqrt[n]n\;$

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
But at the limit of $n \rightarrow \infty$ this number is infinite, and the problem is about this limit. should it matter?

Comment: Again, no: at the limit the number is $\;1\;$ , i.e.: the limit is $\;1\;$ . You can only evaluate limits of real sequences formed by real numbers (in real analysis, of course). Infinity is **not** a real numbers.

Comment: Thank you.
Suppose I insist on solving it with Sandwich Rule, do you have any clever way to come up with a lower series as limit?

Comment: How do you know that $\sqrt[n]n\to 1$ ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What is $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\sqrt[n]{1^n+1^n+...+1^n}}$?

For *any* positive integer $n$, the following is an **identity**:
$$\sqrt[n]{1^n+1^n+...+1^n}=\sqrt[n]{n}$$
The question above is equivalent to ask what is $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\sqrt[n]{n}}$.

This is a well known limit and it appears in examples in lots of textbooks in real analysis. It is a fact that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\sqrt[n]{n}}=1$. The proof in Rudin's *Principle of Real Analysis* uses the binomial theorem (and the sandwich theorem!). The trick there is writing $x_n=\sqrt[n]{n}-1$ and observe that
$$
n=(1+x_n)^n\geq \frac{n(n-1)}{2}x_n^2,\quad x_n\ge 0,
$$
which implies
$$
0\le x_n\le \sqrt{\frac{2}{n-1}}.
$$

See also this post: [Intuitive reason why $\sqrt[n]n\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2354280/9464)

### What goes wrong in the argument for $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\sqrt[n]{1^n+1^n+...+1^n}}=\infty$?

> Since $n \rightarrow \infty$ we have infinite amounts of $1$'s. Therefore we virtually have $\infty$ under the $\sqrt[n]{\phantom{1}}$ sign.

This argument is [not even wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_even_wrong). The symbol $\infty$ is *not* a real number. Beginners in real analysis should strictly follow definitions regarding any statements containing the symbol $\infty$ or the word "infinite". In the level of "intuition", note that in the expression 
$$
\sqrt[n]{\underbrace{1^n+\cdots+1^n}_{n \textrm{ terms}}},
$$
 not only the radicand $n=\underbrace{1^n+\cdots+1^n}_{n \textrm{ terms}}$ goes larger as $n$ becomes larger, *the index* $n$ in the radical $\sqrt[n]{\phantom{1}}$ becomes larger too!

### What is $\lim_{n\to \infty}{\sqrt[n]{1^n+2^n+...+n^n}}$?

$$
\sqrt[n]{1^n+2^n+...+n^n}\geq \sqrt[n]{n^n}=n
$$
which implies that
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}{\sqrt[n]{1^n+2^n+...+n^n}}=\infty.
$$

Note that in this case, one cannot apply the [sandwich theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) 
for sequence of real numbers which says the following:

Let ${\displaystyle (a_{n}),(c_{n})}$ be two sequences converging to **a real number** $\ell$ , and $(b_{n})$ a sequence. If ${\displaystyle \forall n\geqslant N,N\in \mathbb {N} }$ we have $a_{n}\leqslant b_{n}\leqslant c_{n}$, then $(b_{n})$ also converges to $\ell$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]n$$ is an indeterminate form $\infty^0$.

Taking the logarithm,

$$\log\sqrt[n]n=\frac{\log n}n$$ and the numerator grows much slower than the denominator. By L'Hospital, this limit is also

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n.$$

---

It is a little funny that you are worried by the fact that the sum $1+1+1\cdots1$ diverges ("virtually $\infty$"), while you don't care about $n$ being exactly that sum !

Comment: He wrote he already knows that...and, besides, this limit is unrelated to his problem, in fact, and the OP seems to be confused by this.

Comment: @DonAntonio: my answer is about the form being $\infty^0$, because this is what puzzles the OP: how can an infinite sum lead to a finite value. I am also explaining the OP that there is no dilemma. By the way, the OP didn't answer my question about how he knows that $\sqrt[n]n\to1$.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it must be clear by now that your sequence's limit is $\;\infty\;$, and if you insist in using the sandwich theorem then you could write

$$\infty\xleftarrow[n\leftarrow\infty]{}\sqrt[n]n\,n=\sqrt{n\cdot n^n}\le\sqrt[n]{1^n+\ldots +n^n}\le\infty$$

In this cases though, in which the sequence is clearly non-negative, it is enough to write the left hand inequality, as the right hand one is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

We can get better inequalities than those presented.

$$ n -1 \;  \;   \; \;  < \; \left( \sum_{j=1}^n \;  j^n \right)^{1/n} \;  \; \;  <  n+1  $$

At least two answers point out that the sum is bigger than its final term $n^n,$ taking the $n$th root gives

$$ \color{red}{n  \;  \;   \; \;  < \; \left( \sum_{j=1}^n \;  j^n \right)^{1/n} \;  \; \;  <  n+1}  $$

PROOF:

If we have $f(x) > 0$ and $f'(x) > 0,$  then
$$ \int_{a-1}^{b} \; f(x) \;  dx \;  < \; \sum_{j=a}^b \;  f(j) \; < \; \int_{a}^{b+1} \;  f(x) \; dx   $$

here we are taking $f(x) = x^n,$   then $a=1$ and $b=n.$

$$ \int_{0}^{n} \; x^n \;  dx \;  < \; \sum_{j=1}^n \;  j^n \; < \; \int_{1}^{n+1} \;  x^n \; dx   $$

$$ n^n \left(  \frac{n}{n+1} \right) \;  < \; \sum_{j=1}^n \;  j^n \; < \; \; (n+1)^n - \frac{1}{n+1} <  (n+1)^n  $$

$$ n \; \left(  \frac{n}{n+1} \right)^{1/n} \;  < \; \left( \sum_{j=1}^n \;  j^n \right)^{1/n} \;  \; \;  <  n+1  $$

$$ n \; \left(  \frac{n}{n+1} \right)  \; <  \; n \; \left(  \frac{n}{n+1} \right)^{1/n} \;  < \; \left( \sum_{j=1}^n \;  j^n \right)^{1/n} \;  \; \;  <  n+1  $$

$$ n \; \left(  \frac{n}{n+1} \right)  \; \;  < \; \left( \sum_{j=1}^n \;  j^n \right)^{1/n} \;  \; \;  <  n+1  $$

NOTE that
$$  \frac{n-1}{n} < \frac{n}{n+1}  $$

$$n \; \left(  \frac{n-1}{n} \right)  \; \;   \; \;  < \; \left( \sum_{j=1}^n \;  j^n \right)^{1/n} \;  \; \;  <  n+1  $$

$$n -1 \;  \;   \; \;  < \; \left( \sum_{j=1}^n \;  j^n \right)^{1/n} \;  \; \;  <  n+1  $$

Answer (score -2):

Hints:

- ${\sqrt[n]{1^n+2^n+...+n^n}}\ge \sqrt[n]{n^n} =n$
- $n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I could add $n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$, but I thought that would be obvious

Comment: Did you read the question ? Seriously ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Using $\sqrt[n]{n}$ as a lower bound will not allow the sandwich rule to be used

Comment: Ok, this confirms you didn't read the question.

Comment: @YvesDaoust My reading is that the question is asking about finding the limit of $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\sqrt[n]{1^n+2^n+...+n^n}}$ by the sandwich rule